# audio command - where is it located?

Tags: command-line, sound

ubuntu 22.10

if I enter 'audio' this command turns on my speakers (btw I don't get why they are turned off every time I reboot)
but 'which audio' outputs nothing
and 'whereis audio' outputs 'audio'

Can anybody explain what's going on here?

TIA

Comment: Perhaps it is an alias or shell function? What does `type audio` say?

Comment: Solved! 'type audio' says 'audio ist ein Alias von »systemctl --user start pulseaudio'
Thanks!